# java: looping on the two boolean values (false, true)

Tags: java, loops, boolean

This is a stylistic question. I want to loop twice with a variable `on` which is set to false, then to true. Which of these is clearer:

A)

```
for (final boolean on : new boolean[] { false, true} )
{
   doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(on);
}
```

B)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
   final boolean on = (i == 1);
   doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(on);
}
```

C) something else

---

edit: Murphy's law of unintended interpretations comes into play... the use case I have originally looked something like this instead of doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag:

```
for (final boolean on : new boolean[] { false, true} )
{
   JButton button = on ? onButton : offButton;
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      doStuffLaterBasedOnABooleanFlag(on);
      }
   }
}
```

But I think I like Brendan's answer, I'll just refactor the loop contents into a separate method:

```
doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(false);
doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(true);

   ...

private void doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(final boolean on)
{
   JButton button = on ? onButton : offButton;
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      doStuffLaterBasedOnABooleanFlag(on);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess you accidentally answered your own question then and I just helped you realize it?

Comment: My personal preference is: `for (boolean option : Arrays.asList(false, true))`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since it's two lines, I'd just skip the loop and do:

```
doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(false);
doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(true);
```

Less code, more obvious, more efficient.

Comment: I prefer this answer. Simple, clear, and impossible to misinterpret.

Comment: i like that. the for, final, i = 0 while <2 with i == 1?!? and whatever is way too complicated. just call the method twice! :) i had to delete my answer because i've got it wrong from looking at the question too loosely. two simple method calls are much easier to read.

Comment: I got the order wrong at first but it's fixed (false then true). Thanks stmax.

Comment: I like this too. My real code didn't have two method calls, it had about 5 lines of stuff including an inner anonymous class, which I didn't want to repeat twice. For some reason I was missing the obvious (?) refactoring into a method call, and using the do-it-in-a-loop approach instead.

Comment: Being a "complicator" by nature, having this one coming at top makes my day!

Answer (score 13):

Another option would be to avoid the boolean and use an enum:

```
enum Mode { APPEND, REPLACE } // or whatever your boolean indicated
```

You could then either iterate:

```
for(Mode m : Mode.values()) doStuff(m);
```

Or do the calls directly:

```
doStuff(Mode.APPEND);
doStuff(Mode.REPLACE);
```

The advantage of this would be that the API indicates more clearly what's happening.

Comment: Awesome.  You might even end up putting the code that WAS in your loop into your Mode class itself, Mode.APPEND.doStuff().  Otherwise doStuff is a non-OO utility method--yuck.

Comment: @Bill K: I agree, but doStuff() in my case is a non-static method that needs access to other non-static methods.

Comment: Enums methods can be non-static, and have access to other items inside the enum.  They are very powerful, in fact.  enums are full-featured classes, just limited to pre-defined instances.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use a loop, I would go with (a).  While it's novel, it's also clear and efficient.  I might move the boolean array to a private static, to avoid recreating the array every time.

But I like Brendan's answer better.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done directly within a for loop, without creating a `new` array.

```
for (boolean on=false, done=false; !done; done=on, on=true) {
    System.out.println("on="+on+", done="+done);
}
```

Output:

```
on=false, done=false
on=true, done=false
```

This isn't the most clear way, so I wouldn't use this approach unless it were in some kind of inner loop where it would be executed a large number of times.

Comment: I don't think this way is *clearer* than (A) or (B).  But it is a one-line loop that doesn't require allocations.  So it might be useful to someone.  BTW, stylistically, I think (B) is the best way as Java newbies who know any other programming languages will probably understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the loop, I'm also really uncomfortable with the use of booleans in this way.

What about something like:

```
  ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      doStuffLaterBasedOnABooleanFlag(event.getSource() == onButton);
    }
  };
  onButton.addActionListener(myListener);
  offButton.addActionListener(myListener);
```

That still leaves the boolean within the listener, but without knowing what the doStuffLater method does that's as far as we can go.

Comment: I need the boolean. I can't post my real code, it's more complicated than this, and I have two lists of UI components, one handled one way, the other handled the other way.

Answer (score 0):

More fancy loop:

```
IntStream.range(0, 2).forEach(x -> {
    boolean flag = x == 0;
    doStuffBasedOnABooleanFlag(flag);
});
```