# What is the most elegant way to loop TWICE in C

Tags: c, loops, iterator

Many times I need to do things TWICE in a for loop. Simply I can set up a for loop with an iterator and go through it twice:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 // Do stuff
}
```

Now I am interested in doing this as SIMPLY as I can, perhaps without an initializer or iterator? Are there any other, really simple and elegant, ways of achieving this?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? Why not just put two lines in?

Comment: All I can think of is ugly and stupid ways of doing it. Like fork. :)

Comment: Why not do it right the first time ;)

Comment: One thing that none of the answers seems to pick up on is how big the body of the loop is (though the top-voted answer wraps it in a function, which covers the case) or whether the body of the loop references the loop counter.  If it doesn't, then the answers are OK; if the loop counter is referenced, then at least you have to pass a value into the function - assuming you go with the function approach (which I would).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I don't think he would use the loop counter, since the loop is being introduced _only_ to run the code twice. What could happen, though, is that the code uses other local variables or parameters declared in the enclosing function. In that case, these variable should be passed as arguments to the extracted function.

Comment: You might find interesting responses on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383209

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this??

```
void DostuffFunction(){}

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i, DostuffFunction());
```

Regards,
Pablo.

Answer (score 60):

This is elegant because it looks like a triangle; and triangles are elegant.

```
i = 0; 
here: dostuff(); 
i++; if ( i == 1 ) goto here;
```

Comment: +1 for mocking the ambiguity of OP's requirement in a way that made me laugh

Comment: Personally, I find only isosceles and equilateral triangles to be elegant.

Comment: +1 but your last statement ends with a colon instead of a semicolon. Fix the typo.

Comment: @Les: I think goto here is part of the mocking.

Comment: -1: This is funny but really should not be the top answer to the question.

Comment: This is the worst method ever

Comment: it'd be funnier if you change 'here' to 'hell'

Answer (score 42):

Encapsulate it in a function and call it twice.

```
void do_stuff() {
  // Do Stuff
}

// .....

do_stuff();
do_stuff();
```

**Note:** if you use variables or parameters of the enclosing function in the *stuff* logic, you can pass them as arguments to the [extracted](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) `do_stuff` function.

Comment: if you inline the function, you won't even have the function call overhead

Comment: @Sam: Assuming that doesn't mess up the cache.

Answer (score 33):

If its only twice, and you want to avoid a loop, **just write the darn thing twice**.

```
statement1;
statement1;  // (again)
```

Answer (score 16):

If the loop is too verbose for you, you can also define an alias for it:

```
#define TWICE for (int _index = 0; _index < 2; _index++)
```

This would result into that code:

```
TWICE {
    // Do Stuff
}

// or

TWICE
    func();
```

I would only recommend to use this macro if you have to do this very often, I think else the plain for-loop is more readable.

Comment: `TWICE { TWICE ... }` oops.

Comment: @jweyrich: Since both variable declarations are in different scopes, the second _index should shadow the first one and hence it should work. But to be honest I haven't tried it out.

Comment: or #define TWICE(index) ( for (index = 0; index < 2; index++) ) then call with TWICE(i) { ... }

Comment: `#define NTIME(n) for (int _index = 0; _index < n; _index++)`

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, [this](https://gist.github.com/phimuemue/891232a68c6b6ea64170) is not for C, but for C++ only, but does exactly what you want:

Just include the header, and you can write something like this:

```
10 times {
  // Do stuff
}
```

I'll try to rewrite it for C as well.

Comment: I want to +1 for brilliantly useful and readable abuse of the language, but I don't think this will work for C. :(

Comment: @ChrisLutz After some time, I was able to implement the same syntax (with some restrictions and much more work). You can see how it can be done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971752/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-loop-twice-in-c/22281139#22281139).

Answer (score 9):

So, after some time, here's an approach that enables you to write the following in pure C:

```
2 times {
  do_something()
}
```

#### Example:

You'll have to include [this little thing](https://gist.github.com/phimuemue/9445548) as a simple header file (I always called the file `extension.h`). Then, you'll be able to write programs in the style of:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"extension.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    3 times printf("Hello.\n");
    3 times printf("Score: 0 : %d\n", _);
    2 times {
        printf("Counting: ");
        9 times printf("%d ", _);
        printf("\n");
    }
    5 times {
        printf("Counting up to %d: ", _);
        _ times printf("%d ", _);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Features:

- Simple notation of simple loops (in the style depicted above)
- Counter is implicitly stored in a variable called `_` (a simple underscore).
- Nesting of loops allowed.

#### Restrictions (and how to (partially) circumvent them):

- Works only for a certain number of loops (which is - "of course" - reasonable, since you only would want to use such a thing for "small" loops). Current implementation supports a maximum of 18 iterations (higher values result in undefined behaviour). Can be adjusted in header file by changing the size of array `_A`.
- Only a certain nesting depth is allowed. Current implementation supports a nesting depth of 10. Can be adjusted by redefining the macro `_Y`.

#### Explanation:

You can see the [full (=de-obfuscated) source-code here](https://gist.github.com/phimuemue/9445584). Let's say we want to allow up to 18 loops.

- **Retrieving upper iteration bound:** The basic idea is to have an array of `char`s that are initially all set to 0 (this is the array `counterarray`). If we issue a call to e.g. `2 times {do_it;}`, the *macro* `times` shall set the second element of `counterarray` to `1` (i.e. `counterarray[2] = 1`). In C, it is possible to swap index and array name in such an assignment, so we can write `2[counterarray] = 1` to acchieve the same. This is exactly what the macro `times` does as first step. Then, we can later scan the array `counterarray` until we find an element that is not 0, but 1. The corresponding index is then the upper iteration bound. It is stored in variable `searcher`. Since we want to support nesting, we have to store the upper bound *for each nesting depth* separately, this is done by `searchermax[depth]=searcher+1`.
- **Adjusting current nesting depth:** As said, we want to support nesting of loops, so we have to keep track of the current nesting depth (done in the variable `depth`). We increment it by one if we start such a loop.
- **The actual counter variable:** We have a "variable" called `_` that implicitly gets assigned the current counter. In fact, we store one counter for each nesting depth (all stored in the array `counter`. Then, `_` is just another macro that retrieves the proper counter for the current nesting depth from this array.
- **The actual for loop:** We take the for loop into parts:

  - We initialize the counter for the current nesting depth to 0 (done by `counter[depth] = 0`).
  - The iteration step is the most complicated part: We have to check if the loop at the current nesting depth has reached its end. If so, we have do update the nesting depth accordingly. If not, we have to increment the current nesting depth's counter by 1. The variable `lastloop` is 1 if this is the last iteration, otherwise 0, and we adjust the current nesting depth accordingly. The main problem here is that we have to write this as a sequence of expressions, all separated by commata, which requires us to write all these conditions in a very non-straight-forward way.
  - The "increment step" of the for loop consists of only one assignment, that increments the appropriate counter (i.e. the element of `counter` of the proper nesting depth) and assigns this value to our "counter variable" `_`.

Comment: This is fantastic. It looks like you can assign to `_` in this implementation - bug or feature?

Comment: @ChrisLutz To be honest, I did not intend to allow this, but now it's done, let's just call it a feature :)

Answer (score 4):

What abelenky said.

And if your `{ // Do stuff }` is multi-line, make it a function, and call that function -- twice.

Answer (score 4):

Many people suggest writing out the code twice, which is fine if the code is short.  There is, however, a size of code block which would be awkward to copy but is not large enough to merit its own function (especially if that function would need an excessive number of parameters).  My own normal idiom to run a loop 'n' times is

```
  i = number_of_reps;
  do
  {
    ... whatever
  } while(--i);
```

In some measure because I'm frequently coding for an embedded system where the up-counting loop is often inefficient enough to matter, and in some measure because it's easy to see the number of repetitions.  Running things twice is a bit awkward because the most efficient coding on my target system

```
  bit rep_flag;

  rep_flag = 0;
  do
  {
    ...
  } while(rep_flag ^= 1); /* Note: if loop runs to completion, leaves rep_flag clear */
```

doesn't read terribly well.  Using a numeric counter suggests the number of reps can be varied arbitrarily, which in many instances won't be the case.  Still, a numeric counter is probably the best bet.

Comment: If you know the number of repetitions, just use a `for` loop. `do..while` suggests the idea of indefinitely/continuously repeating a task until a condition is met. Used like this, it offers no significant advantage over a for loop except that the number of repetitions and the loop decrementer have suddenly been separated by a body of code.

Comment: @dreamlax: My counting idiom is most typically used on loops which are five lines or less, and the most common reason for me to say "i=16;" immediately before a "do" statement will be for a counting-down-to-zero loop.  It may not be the most common idiom, but I find it's nicer to be consistent in that pattern than to use for() loops in places where speed and code space don't matter and use the do-while() when they do, especially since (in small-micro development) it's often not possible to tell in advance whether code space is going to matter.

Comment: @dreamlax: BTW, when developing for the PC, or for embedded compilers that recognize the normal loop idiom and can optimize for it (e.g. the TMS 32050 compiler will use the hardware loop facility) I generally use the 'normal' for loop; I mainly avoid it on platforms where it often poses a meaningful efficiency difference.  If I have an inner loop where counting up would increase execution time 50% or more (it happens), it seems cleaner to have an outer loop use the same pattern than to use 'for' for one and 'do-while' for the other.  YMMV.

Comment: What, you would miss a perfect opportunity to use `while (i --> 0)` ?!

Comment: @supercat: Consider an example where the loop counter is incremented/decremented by a value other than 1. With a `do..while` loop, you may know the initial value of the counter but will not know how it is affected with each iteration until you have reached the end of the loop body. With a `for` loop, you can immediately see all of the information pertaining to how the loop will execute. In my opinion, a `for` loop should always be used if the number of iterations can be determined prior to entering the loop. [...]

Comment: [...]  If the compiler cannot figure out the most efficient way to loop for the target architecture, chances are you end up writing it in assembly anyway.

Comment: @dreamlax: I try to avoid writing code in assembly language when I can avoid it, though when moving to new platforms I try to familiarize myself with the machine code generated by various constructs.  In a lot of cases, especially on the PIC, it's possible to small write loops in such a way that a straightforward translation into machine code will generate essentially the same instruction sequence as hand-written code, though sometimes it's necessary to do things in non-idiomatic fashion.  For example, there are at least five ways of copying one bit to another, at a cost of 3-5 instructions:

Comment: `bit1=0; bit1|=bit2;` and `bit1=1; bit1&=bit2;` both take three instructions, `bit1|=bit2; bit1&=bit2;` and `bit1&=bit2; bit1|=bit2;` both take four, and `if (bit2) bit1=1; else bit1=0;` takes five instructions executes in 4-5 cycles.  In cases where the difference between the above would be important, I explicitly write them out rather than `bit1=bit2;` [for which I think the compiler's normal behavior is `bit1&=bit2; bit1|=bit2;`].

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports this just put the declaration inside the `for` statement:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
 // Do stuff
}
```

This is as elegant and efficient as it can be. Modern compilers can do loop unrolling and all that stuff, trust them. If you don't trust them, check the assembler.

And it has one little advantage to all other solutions, for everybody it just reads, "do it twice".

Comment: It's not a question of performance, but a question of aesthetics.

Comment: Agree with Jens, it is aesthetically please to some to have a simple for statement.  When I see the for(int i=0; i<2; ++i), I immediately read "do it twice", and the i=val is a little extra info.

Answer (score 3):

> As [Edsger W. Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) himself put it : "two or more, use a for". No need to be any simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt:

```
for(i=2;i--;) /* Do stuff */
```

This solution has many benefits:

- Shortest form possible, I claim (13 chars)
- Still, readable
- Includes initialization
- The amount of repeats ("2") is visible in the code
- Can be used as a toggle (1 or 0) inside the body e.g. for alternation
- Works with single instruction, instruction body or function call
- Flexible (doesn't have to be used only for "doing twice")
- Dijkstra compliant ;-)

From comment:

```
for (i=2; i--; "Do stuff");
```

Comment: Alternatively: for (i=2; i--; /*Do stuff*/);

Answer (score 2):

Use function:

```
func();
func();
```

Or use macro (not recommended):

```
#define DO_IT_TWICE(A) A; A

DO_IT_TWICE({ x+=cos(123); func(x); })
```

Comment: Yes. And they are widely used. Even in Boost.

Comment: @Pavel: Boost uses them wisely. This is not wise.

Comment: That's why it is not recommended.

Comment: Then why post it in the answer? :)

Comment: One should know all possibilities. Freedom of choice is good. It is one of the first principles put in C++ design.

Comment: Don't *teach* bad programming. One can know all the ways with trivial knowledge of macros, and also know not to do it. I simply fail to see the reason to say "this is awful, here you go". Just don't spread the awful.

Comment: There are many bad incomplete tutorials out there. Newcomer will read one that does not mention "avoid macroses if you can". And he will use macroses. I prefer to tell about bad programming and mention that it is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Good rule: three or more, do a *for*.

I think I read that in Code Complete, but I could be wrong. So in your case you don't need a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C++0x lambda support:

```
template <typename T> void twice(T t)
{
    t();
    t();
}

twice([](){ /*insert code here*/ });
```

Or:

```
twice([]()
{ 
    /*insert code here*/ 
});
```

Which doesn't help you since you wanted it for C.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest possible without preprocessor/template/duplication tricks:

```
for(int i=2; i--; ) /*do stuff*/;
```

Note that the decrement happens once right at the beginning, which is why this will loop precisely twice with the indices `1` and `0` as requested.

Alternatively you can write

```
for(int i=2; i--; /*do stuff*/) ;
```

But that's purely a difference of taste.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing is somewhat complicated wrap it in a function and call that function twice?  (This depends on how many local variables your `do stuff` code relies on).

You could do something like

```
void do_stuff(int i){
    // do stuff
}

do_stuff(0);
do_stuff(1);
```

But this may get extremely ugly if you are working on a whole bunch of local variables.

Answer (score 0):

**jump** instruction is pretty slow,so if you write the lines one after the other,it would work faster,than writing a loop. but modern compilers are very,very smart and the optimizations are great (if they are allowed,of course). if you have turned on your compiler's optimizations,you don't care the way,you write it - with loop or not (:

**EDIT** : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/compiler_optimizations just take a look (:

Answer (score 0):

```
//dostuff
  stuff;
//dostuff (Attention I am doing the same stuff for the :**2nd** time)
  stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a comment

```
/* Do the following stuff twice */
```

then,
1) use the for loop
2) write the statement twice, or
3) write a function and call the function twice
do not use macros, as earlier stated, macros are evil.

(My answer's almost a triangle)

Comment: It seems like the comment would just add noise. If someone can't tell that you're doing something twice from the code, you're either doing it wrong or they shouldn't be looking at your code.

Comment: Many believe in self documenting code, I came up in the school of commenting code (or as I like to call it "self verifying code").  I find comments to be like redundancy in hardware, it costs more but real intentions (inspite of the implementation) are more obvious.  Yes, comments can go out of date because others don't keep them up to date, nothing's perfect.  Comments are probably a SO discussion in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

What is elegance? How do you measure it? Is someone paying you to be elegant? If so how do they determine the dollar-to-elegance conversion?

When I ask myself, "how should this be written," I consider the priorities of the person paying me. If I'm being paid to write fast code, control-c, control-v, done. If I'm being paid to write code fast, well.. same thing. If I'm being paid to write code that occupies the smallest amount of space on the screen, I short the stock of my employer.

Comment: There's a simple metric for "elegance"...

It's the number of WTFs/minute spoken by whoever has to maintain the code after the copy/paste cowboy has cut and run.

You might short the stock of a company that values maintainability, I'll short the stock of one that willfully takes on tech debt with wild abandon.

Answer (score 0):

Close to your example, elegant and efficient:

```
for (i = 2; i; --i)
{
    /* Do stuff */
}
```

Here's why I'd recommend that approach:

- It initializes the iterator to the number of iterations, which makes intuitive sense.
- It uses decrement over increment so that the loop test expression is a comparison to zero (the "i;" can be interpreted as "is i true?" which in C means "is i non-zero"), which may optimize better on certain architectures.
- It uses pre-decrement as opposed to post-decrement in the counting expression for the same reason (may optimize better).
- It uses a for loop instead of do/while or goto or XOR or switch or macro or any other trick approach because readability and maintainability are more elegant and important than clever hacks.
- It doesn't require you to duplicate the code for "Do stuff" so that you can avoid a loop.  Duplicated code is an abomination and a maintenance nightmare.

If "Do stuff" is lengthy, move it into a function and give the compiler permission to inline it if beneficial.  Then call the function from within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I like Chris Case's solution (up here), but C language doesn't have default parameters.

My solution:

```
bool cy = false;
do {
    // Do stuff twice
} while (cy = !cy);
```

If you want, you could do different things in the two cycle by checking the boolean variable (maybe by ternary operator).

Answer (score -1):

```
void loopTwice (bool first = true)
{
    // Recursion is your friend
    if (first) {loopTwice(false);}

    // Do Stuff
    ...
}
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but this is simple to read, and pretty simply to write. There might even be a way to eliminate the bool parameter, but this is what I came up with in 20 seconds.

Comment: This isn't simple to read. `loopTwice(false)` actually means "do once".

Comment: So, perhaps: 

void loopTwice (bool second = false)
{
    if (!second) { loopTwice(true); }

    // Do Stuff
}

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it is

```
for(auto value: {1,2}){
}
```

This is also handy if you need a counter value which is not just counting up. It can have any values, also duplicates.

```
for(auto value: {2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 10}){
}
```

Comment: OP post was tagged [tag:c]. This answer will not work for C, and it only works for C++ with `#include <initializer_list>`.